# Using Cypher to create new list from two lists in Neo4j with a function

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two lists with two columns in each like these:

```
with [{Word:'word1',B1Weight:0.3},{Word:'word2',B1Weight:0.2}] as BOWS1,
[{Word:'word2',B2Weight:1.5},{Word:'word3',B2Weight:2.0}] as BOWS2
```

How  would I get a single list with a "Word" column with three words, and a "NewWeight" column that equals: (B1Weight * 10) + B2Weight
so that if a word only exists in one list, it's weight from the other list is 0. 
I can get a list of distinct words adding this:

```
unwind BOWS1 + BOWS2 as myList
with distinct myList.Word as words
return words
```

I'm not sure how to get the weights from the lists and create a new result column. I would expect a result like:

```
[{Word:'word1',NewWeight:3.0},{Word:'word2',NewWeight:3.5},{Word:'word3',NewWeight:2.0}]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close. You need the aggregation function [sum](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/#functions-sum):

```
with
    [{Word:'word1',B1Weight:0.3},{Word:'word2',B1Weight:0.2}] as BOWS1,
    [{Word:'word2',B2Weight:1.5},{Word:'word3',B2Weight:2.0}] as BOWS2
unwind
    BOWS1 + BOWS2 as wd
with
    wd.Word as word,
    sum(wd.B1Weight) as w1,
    sum(wd.B2Weight) as w2
return
    collect({
        Word: word,
        NewWeight: w1 * 10 + w2
    })
```

P.S. This works, because the following query will return one:

```
unwind [null, 1] as i 
return SUM(i) // = 1
```